# Datediff between hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

My data looks like this:

```
Col1     Col2     output
09:35    16:00    6,25 <-- need help with this
```

I would like to have the output show `H,m` (hours,minuts)

```
Datediff(Hours,Col1,Col2)
```

give me 7.

I don't want to make any parameters if possible only use some simple functions.

Comment: why do you want a format like that ? Wouldn't a time format be much better ? You are trying to subtract a time from a time to get a new time, then manipulating with the format instead of keeping the time format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would just do this explicitly, by taking the difference in minutes and doing the numeric calculations:

```
select (cast(datediff(minute, col1, col2) / 60 as varchar(255)) + ',' +
        right('00' + cast(datediff(minute, col1, col2) % 60 as varchar(255)), 2)
       )
```

Answer (score 3):

What about getting the date diff in minutes and converting the result to the string you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '09:35', '16:00') / 60, ':', DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '09:35', '16:00') % 60 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the following solutions:

```
-- Solution 1: Mathematical correct time
CREATE TABLE #time(col1 time, col2 time)

INSERT INTO #time(col1, col2)
VALUES(N'09:35',N'16:00'),(N'8:10',N'22:44')

SELECT col1, col2, CONVERT(decimal(10,2),DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Col1,Col2))/60  as [output]
FROM #time

DROP TABLE #time
GO

-- Solution 2: Your expected value
CREATE TABLE #time(col1 time, col2 time)

INSERT INTO #time(col1, col2)
VALUES(N'09:35',N'16:00'),(N'8:10',N'22:44')

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Col1,Col2)/60 as [hours], DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Col1,Col2)%60 as [minutes],
    -- Contated values:
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Col1,Col2)/60 + (CONVERT(decimal(10,2),DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Col1,Col2)%60))/100 as [output]
FROM #time

DROP TABLE #time
```

Output of `Solution 1`:

```
col1             col2             output
---------------- ---------------- ---------------------------------------
09:35:00.0000000 16:00:00.0000000 6.416666
08:10:00.0000000 22:44:00.0000000 14.566666
```

Output of `Solution 2`:

```
hours       minutes     output
----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
6           25          6.250000
14          34          14.340000
```

You can still round/convert the values to match your 2 digit pattern - if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the second col1 time is bigger than the col2 time, you will get a funky result.

By simply casting both times to datetime, you can subtract them:

```
SELECT 
  cast(cast('16:00' as datetime) - cast('09:35' as datetime) as time(0))
```

Result:

```
06:25:00
```

In case you an similar format (I would prefer the time format):

```
SELECT 
  stuff(left(cast(cast('16:00' as datetime) 
    - cast('09:35' as datetime) as time(0)), 5), 3,1,',')
```

Result:

```
06,25
```